# Decode/encode from big5 to utf-8 is not working

Tags: python, python-2.7, utf-8, decode

I am trying very basic character set conversion like iconv does but not able to figure out why its not working. I am using python decode, encode routines but looks like missing on something very basic.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print ("wrong input")
        sys.exit(1)

    fi = open(sys.argv[1], "r")
    buf = fi.read()
    fi.close()

    print ("got input: \n{0}".format(buf))

    buf.decode("big5", "strict").encode("utf8", "strict")

    fo = open(sys.argv[2], "w")
    fo.write(buf)
    fo.close()


    print ("changed: \n{0}".format(buf))
```

Input files. hello.big5 is obtained by converting utf file with **iconv**

```
[workspace] > cat hello.utf8 
hello = 你好

[workspace] > cat hello.big5 
hello = �A�n
```

When executed:

```
[workspace] > ./test.py  hello.big5 out
got input: 
hello = �A�n

changed: 
hello = �A�n
```

Can someone point out where I am tripping ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is not modiying `buf` as you appear to be thinking:

```
buf.decode("big5", "strict").encode("utf8", "strict")
```

You can see in the docs for [`encode`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=iterator#str.encode) and [`decode`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=iterator#str.decode). Those methods return *strings* or *unicode objects*, they don't modify the *calling* object. If you want to modify `buf` just assign it the result:

```
buf = buf.decode("big5", "strict").encode("utf8", "strict")
```

Also if you're on Python2 it doesn't make sense to use parenthesis with `print`, can be confusing.